# r how to set x and y ranges in an animation video generated with saveVideo

Tags: r, mpeg

I make mpeg videos using the code below. r.mean is a spatRaster (the format for rasters in the terra package)

```
library(terra)
animation::saveVideo(animate(r.mean, n=1, pause = 0, sub = title_animate, col = rev(colorList), videoName_out))
```

I have included a screenshot of one frame of the animation. There is lots of white space above and below the actual image. I'd like to set the y range from -60 to 90. I've seen one example of use of saveVideo that looks like this with par parameters included in {}

```
saveVideo({
par(xxx, yy, zzz)}, 
some other stuff)
```

But I haven't had any luck making that work.

[image: Screenshot of an animation]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*.

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nlyrs=3)
values(r) <- rep(1:3, ncell(r))
```

You can use the `ani.height` and `ani.width` arguments.

```
animation::saveGIF(animate(r, n=1), ani.height=200, ani.width=300)
```

Comment: Your example data has min and max values in r of 1 and 3. I ran modifications of the command